# How do I solve this (SQL) query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

This is probably one of the simplest queries ever, and I'm probably just making it harder than it has to be, but I need it done.

So, there's three tables:

```
TABLE AGENT
(
A_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
A_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
A_ADDR VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
A_PHN CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
A_EMAIL VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
)

TABLE E_TRANSACTION
(
T_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
T_AMT FLOAT NOT NULL,
T_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
A_ID INTEGER REFERENCES AGENT(A_ID);
)

TABLE ESTATE
(
E_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
E_ADDR VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
T_ID INTEGER REFERENCES E_TRANSACTION(T_ID));
)
```

The query I'm trying to run has to answer this question:
**The Agent who sold the most number of properties between Jan-1-2015 to June-30-2015**

So far, I have this:

```
select A_ID, count(A_ID)
from E_TRANSACTION
where t_date >= '01-Jan-2015' and t_date < '30-June-2015'
group by A_ID;
```

but it's too vague and my instructor has told me to only have the output of the agent who has sold the most properties, in this case, the highest occurrence of A_ID in the E_TRANSACTION table. In other words, it should only output that one A_ID which has the mode number in the A_ID stack within the E_TRANSACTION table which basically displays the transactions made by that agent.

I've tried ORDER BY and GROUP BY by themselves, and I've even tried them together, but I haven't gotten any results.

I tried joining the two tables E_TRANSACTION and AGENT to get the name to come up as well as the A_ID which the name is fixed with, but that didn't work out either. I'm assuming it's because I typed the code wrong and or I was committing illegal actions.

To this moment, I still can't wrap my head around whether to use GROUP BY or ORDER BY, and whatever else I need to get this query to work.

### Additional Info:

- Using Oracle 11g Express Edition (sqlplus)
- Running all of this on SQL command line
- Has just about zero experience with SQL

### Some SQL Info:

insert into AGENT
values(1111, 'Charles Markley', '111-PSHMT Way', '111-112-1122', 'cm@sample.example');

insert into AGENT
values(1112, 'Laurene Lowrey', '1010 Learners St', '101-121-1211', 'll@sample.example');

insert into E_TRANSACTION
values(1001, 30000.50, '12-Jan-2015', 1111);

insert into e_transaction
values(1002, 80000.50, '20-June-2015', 1112);

insert into ESTATE
values(301, '666 Merry Ln', 1001);

insert into ESTATE
values(302, '521 Ball Staint Ct', 1002);

So, as some have mentioned, I haven't given **enough** details for this query.

The attempt initially was to collect the number of transactions made by each Agent, which is discovered by finding how many times each agent's A_ID occurred in the E_TRANSACTION table.

Why I had assumed that would work? I wasn't accounting for there to be multiple ESTATEs associated with a TRANSACTION. I will have to change that in my requirements list. The way I have my code set up now is that there is NO more than one ESTATE per TRANSACTION. So, that means there will only be ONE Agent making that TRANSACTION which get's someone ASSIGNED an ESTATE. So, each ESTATE has one solely unique TRANSACTION ID as well as the AGENT who made the transaction. An agent is allowed to sell up to 5 estates, but those estates only get assigned one transaction ID.

I presented a few lines of dummy-data that has already been implemented in my database. What I can't get is the correct syntax or method needed to complete the query asked of me, which is given above in bold.

If you don't feel like giving me specifics, then please at least work through what I'm doing wrong. Maybe explain why my methods don't work and as to why using GROUP BY or ORDER BY don't work in this example.

Again, any help would be grand.
— *That Random Guy*

Comment: if the required date is "all of june 2014", why are you doing Jan 1 **2015** as the lower date?

Comment: I will give you a hint...feel free to not accept it as you said.  Look into using HAVING which is effectively a WHERE clause for your GROUP BY statement.  You may also want to look into MAX so that you can get the A_ID that has the max count to narrow it down to just that one record.  Good luck!

Comment: @BradLarson - I understand the edit. Does the "random guy" understand the reason?

Comment: @Marc B The question itself is outdated, but I understood what I was asked and decided to change the date. Sorry for the confusion, but just change that to 2015.

Comment: @Ed Heal : I don't quite understand why certain specifications were discarded from my question. I made it as blunt as can be for a reason. All I'm asking for is a little understanding and some explanation(s) as to why my code isn't working & what it lacks—that's it.

Comment: You said "I realize not everything can be handed to me in this life" but then you asked the world (SO) to hand you the perfectly complete answer, on a plate, for nothing in return. Your specifications (demands) were rude, non-constructive and did not add any value to the question. You should be grateful that they were removed - did you notice how people started posting answers only after those "specifications" were discarded?

Comment: @ThatRandomGuy - See Joes' answer above

Comment: @JoeMalpass Not trying to start anything... I honestly would've been fine if I didn't get **any** answers. That's usually the way it goes. I'll have to edit my question and see where this goes. I didn't have time to up on this yesterday, so I'm getting to it now...

Comment: Ah, but have you considered the reason "that's usually the way it goes" might be because of the tone you use? It doesn't have to be that way, you can get good answers to *all* of your questions by asking the right way and following the guidelines. SO is community of like-minded individuals that genuinely want to help each other out. In a giving community like this there really isn't any room for arrogance. I'm trying not to rant; I apologize if it comes across that way, just trying to help everyone get along. FWIW it appears that you have learned from this experience, an overall net gain :)

Comment: @JoeMalpass People shouldn't take it to heart. What I said shouldn't be taken as **rude**. It's the **truth**. Sometimes, that can hurt. I understand people—not just on this site—like to give as little detail as possible in hopes that the OP will learn and get their act together, but that doesn't always work depending on what you're trying to get done. I accept the fact that I left a bit of important information out of my example. That's my fault. I made that error. What I won't apologize for is how I tried to scoop the answer. As I said, I''m learning. What else do I have?

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs"—That's not funny. I feel that this site gives too much power to the people who *try* to help and don't give enough to those that ask. You can only go so far as to reprimand my question. The -6 votes was unnecessary and the lack of understanding from those who decided to put my question on hold was in **their** mind, just.

Comment: I don't like how this site gives that much control over a measly question. I know I agreed to the terms and conditions upon registration, but this site gives too much power to those who don't agree or just wishfully want to down-vote a certain topic without just cause. That's **not** fair. Why a down-vote system is allowed for the question itself is a design flaw. This isn't a competition. I legitimately needed my questions answered, and people assume that I come off as rude for being rational. Who in their right mind wouldn't ask for the answer? Is that not what this is for?

Comment: Random Guy...   if you are considering a career in IT...you should know....your approach is not going to get you anywhere in this field.  You will get chewed up and spit out, over and over.   Nothing personal...so don't take it that way.  But...that is just the way it is out here in professional IT land.   Just the way it is.... and it ain't getting any kinder over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important things here seem to be:

1. `INNER JOIN`
2. `COUNT`
3. `GROUP BY`
4. `ROWNUM`

So the following should do you:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.A_ID, a.A_NAME, COUNT(t.A_ID) AS TRANSACTION_COUNT
                FROM AGENT a
                INNER JOIN E_TRANSACTION t
                  ON t.A_ID = a.A_ID
                GROUP BY a.A_ID, a.A_NAME
                ORDER BY COUNT(t.A_ID) DESC)
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85a8a/6)

### Edit

Note the use of the alias `a` following the `AGENT` table, and `t` following the `E_TRANSACTION` table. These allow fields in these tables to be referred to through the alias, which saves time and space when compared to typing the entire table name.

`JOIN` without a preceding qualifier is the same as `INNER JOIN`. I prefer to use `INNER JOIN` to make my intention obvious.

As far as the time span goes - I think you'd want to add a `WHERE` clause to the inner `SELECT` to limit the rows fetched to the ones for the specific time span you're interested in.

Comment: Can I ask a question? You have listed in your example "a.A_ID" and "t.a_ID". Where did you declare that initially? I guess what I'm trying to say is, are those examples of an **Alias**? Can you describe the difference between the *inner join* and the *join* keywords? I've seen both used, but I'm not quite sure why they're both being suggested if one works over the other.

Comment: Also, another question: How would I be able to account for the time scale? The query asks for this on a specific date-to-date basis. Any ideas on that? You don't need to fix the code, just let me know how, where, and if I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

The Agent who sold the most number of properties between date1 and date 2

Key words :   Agent, Sold, Number ( count ), dates

Agent means you will need :   A_ID in E_Transaction Table, and A_ID in Agent table, and A_Name in agent table Sold & Count means you will need :   Count(*) from Transaction table and  A_ID from Transaction table

So it should end up looking something like this :

Select  A_ID
,   A_NAME
,   Count(T.A_ID) 
From    E_Transaction T 
Inner Join 
Agent   A on A.A_ID = T.A_ID 
Group By 
    T.A_ID 
,   A_NAME
Order By 
    Count(T.A_ID)

Run this, debug as needed since I dont have your DB in my hands I cant do it.

Since you have your data, you can visually confirm whether it landed on the right counts, right agent, etc.

You many also need to bring in Estate, since the same estate could sell more than once, and that could affect the counts, and which agent rises to the top.

If you have specific questions, spell them out, I'll respond.   Just remember, without seeing your data, I/we are at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying only the E_TRANSACTION tables but from the table structure it seems that one transaction can involve more than one estate; so if you want the number of properties you must join tables E_TRANSACTION and ESTATE

```
select * from (
select * from (
select A_ID, count(E_ID) as num
from E_TRANSACTION,ESTATE
where E_TRANSACTION.t_ID=ESTATE.I_ID 
and t_date   >=to_date('01062014','ddmmyyyy') 
and t_date < to_date('01072014','ddmmyyyy')
group by C_ID) 
order by num desc) 
where rownum<=1
```

the query is more like to suit you needs, only joining the two tables gives you **all** the sales so you must sort the data in decending order and get the first rows in order to get the top seller.

that's why I used the two outer selects: 
to order and filter the data

The query could be made more compact using analyitics functions bust since you are beginner I wrote  in a didactic way.
I corrected the way you expressed the date in a format that is more independent from oracle default date/time settings, you query did not consider the 30-jun because of the <, mine it consider all the days of june.

Comment: Excellent point that it looks like a transaction can involve more than one estate.

Comment: Very good point. I wasn't aware of it, however for my purposes, I'll only be applying a 1:1 relationship. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

So using Troy's suggestion on the HAVING clause, you could do something like this: (it worked on one of my tables but I'll use yours)

```
SELECT ET.A_ID, AG.A_NAME
FROM AGENT AG 
JOIN E_TRANSACTION ET
ON ( ET.A_ID = AG.A_ID )
GROUP BY AG.A_ID, AG.A_NAME
HAVING COUNT(ET.A_ID) =
( SELECT MAX(COUNT(A_ID) FROM E_TRANSACTION
WHERE A_ID IN ( SELECT A_ID FROM AGENT )
GROUP BY A_ID )
```

This should get you the answer you're looking for - since the count would equal the max count from the table. There are probably more advanced ways to do this using analytics, but I'm not strong in those functions.

Comment: This will not address multiple property transactions.  He has to return the agent that sold the most properties...not the agent that had the most transactions.  But you pretty much hit the nail on the head as to what I was thinking.  @Giovanni pointed out the need to join with the ESTATE table to get the true number of properties sold.

Comment: Agreed, although from the looks of the tables, I'd assume you can sell one property per transaction. But if the properties were apartments (individual), I suppose one transaction could cover multiples.

Comment: I didn't think that far and didn't intend for their to be single transactions holding multiple estates. My requirements are to only have a transaction ID associated with an estate. So, while I agree that this solution may not have worked if the scenario had been more realistic, it will function for my purposes. Please take a look at my edit above to see what  I'm talking about.